# Is this question out of place?

Tags: discussion

Is this [question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/263321/14414) out of place here, as I could not garner any attention/comment? How would you classify this and what would you suggest, in a situation similar to this question.

Comment: Your question is open, and it got two upvotes and no downvote -- this clearly suggests that your question is not out of place. That you didn't get any answer or comment may have multiple reasons, one of them being that you didn't give a top-level tag and that the right people therefore didn't see it. What you can do is to edit your question (e.g. add a top-level tag, possibly improve the formulation etc.), or -- once you have gathered a few more points -- to start a bounty.